# Adding paragraph text input by loop [TypeScript]

Tags: loops, typescript

I have this variable in my TypeScript :

```
data = {
    "paragraphs": [
        { "paragraph": "" }
    ]
}
```

When the screen is loaded, I want to add the `{ "paragraph": "" }` in the array to become like as follow.

```
data = {
    "paragraphs": [
        { "paragraph": "" },
        { "paragraph": "" },
        { "paragraph": "" }
    ]
}
```

So what I did was, I make a for loop to keep adding the `{ "paragraph": "" }` in the array but it's not completed yet.

```
let dataParag = 3;      // The int value will keep changing based on data from database
for (var i = this.data.paragraphs.length; i <= dataParag; i++) {
    this.data.paragraphs = [
        { "paragraph": "" }     // The paragraph will be keep added in here but I don't have any idea on how to add it
    ];
}
```

Is there any good way to add it dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh nevermind as I found the solution for this. This is how I do the thing :

```
let dataParag = 3;
for (var i = 1; i < dataParag; i++) {
    this.data.paragraphs.push({ "paragraph": "" });
}
```